# BeanCreationException with Spring and Jackson API

Tags: spring, jackson

I am getting following exception while trying to use Jackson API with Spring 3.0.6. I have jackson jars of v1.8.9 (core-asl, mapper-asl) into the classpath but still due to some conflicting jars I am facing the error ::

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#8': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.codehaus.jackson.type.JavaType.<init>(Ljava/lang/Class;I)V
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:965) [org.springframework.beans-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:911) [org.springframework.beans-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:485) [org.springframework.beans-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456) [org.springframework.beans-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:270) [org.springframework.beans-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:]
    ... 30 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.codehaus.jackson.type.JavaType.<init>(Ljava/lang/Class;I)V
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:141) [org.springframework.beans-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:74) [org.springframework.beans-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:958) [org.springframework.beans-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:]
    ... 34 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.codehaus.jackson.type.JavaType.<init>(Ljava/lang/Class;I)V
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.type.TypeBase.<init>(TypeBase.java:13) [jackson-mapper-asl-1.8.9.jar:]
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.type.SimpleType.<init>(SimpleType.java:39) [jackson-mapper-asl-1.8.9.jar:]
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.type.SimpleType.constructUnsafe(SimpleType.java:56) [jackson-mapper-asl-1.8.9.jar:]
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper.<clinit>(ObjectMapper.java:188) [jackson-mapper-asl-1.8.9.jar:]
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter.<init>(MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter.java:56) [org.springframework.web-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) [:1.6.0_24]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57) [:1.6.0_24]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) [:1.6.0_24]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:532) [:1.6.0_24]
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:126) [org.springframework.beans-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:]
    ... 36 more
```

Answer (score 3):

The correct version dependency of Jackson for Spring 3.0.6 is 1.4.2(per Spring's pom), try replacing 1.8.9 with this version, it should work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your reply. However, I could solve out the issue doing some R&D... I need not go down to Jackson v1.4.2, instead I used the same version with slight modification in JBoss configuration itself.

In JBoss, go to modules/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-core-asl/main/

Here JBoss is using its own version of Jackson API (though we had different version in classpath). So I copied the v1.8.9 and made changes accordingly in  module.xml (in same directory). Similar thing was repeated for mapper jars v1.8.9.

With this I could fix the issue and run things again.... :)